# Imagemagick: Converting specified color leaves slight border

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to overlay a green image over another image, and then convert the green color to transparent. The code I use is below. It works okay, however it leaves a slight green border. What's the best way to have this green border not show up? I tried using fuzz, however results with this vary. Sometimes it cuts out other colors. Is  there a better way to prevent the green border than using fuzz?

```
convert image.png ../greenoverlay.png -layers merge image.png;
convert image.png -fuzz 41% -transparent \#00FF00 final.png;
```

[image: final.png]

Thank you all!

Comment: If there's any anti-aliasing in your overlay, the merge will create semi-green pixels that will be nearly impossible to remove.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I added a command: `convert overlay.png -fuzz 99% -fill #00FF00 -opaque #00FF00 overlay.png` to fix the antialiasing on the overlay, but it seems imagemagick adds antialiasing on the merge. I've tried  `convert image.png ../greenoverlay.png +antialias -layers merge image.png;` to fix this, but it doesn't seem to help much

Comment: You could try expanding the green mask a little first. If you provide it, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It turned out to be an issue with me resizing the overlay before I layered it. I got it to work using this command `convert overlay.png -resize 1280x720\! -fuzz 99% -fill
 \#FF0000 -opaque \#0FF000 -alpha off -fuzz 0% -fill \#00FF00 -opaque \#000000 -
transparent \#FF0000 overlay.png`